# How to hibernate windows 10 without enabling the "show hibernate in the menu" setting?

Tags: windows, windows-10

I was thinking about a command in Command prompt or sth, any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can run `shutdown /h` from a command prompt.

Additionally, you could stick that in a .BAT file on your desktop etc...

For extra flair and pazzazz, you could put a `/t 30` on it for a 30 second countdown, and then have a 2nd batch file to `shutdown /a` (abort) if you change your mind.